# SES url in coldfusion - No MVC

Tags: iis, url, coldfusion, url-rewriting

Got this url

http://localhost:8500/users.cfm?userid=John

that loads the user's profile by getting the users details from the db

```
WHERE userid = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#url.userid#">
```

How can the same profile be accessed like this:

http://localhost:8500/John

Instead of users having to type "users.cfm?userid=John", they simply type the user id of the person whom they want to view.

On CF9, IIS7

I may need to install http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite for the solution, please advice.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Using URLRewrite, have the rewriter set the requested URL (e.g. `/John`) as a request header and forward it to a single .cfm file (i.e. a [front controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern)). In the .cfm file (e.g. frontcontroller.cfm) read out the request header (i.e. `GetHttpRequestData().headers`) and process accordingly -> `users.cfm?userid=john`.

Comment: If you like the idea of using OnRequest or OnMissingTemplate, you could use URLRewrite to append /index.cfm to directory-only requests.  Not sure what the [dis]advantages would be.

Comment: Thank you, will investigate this.

Answer (score 1):

Off-hand, maybe you could use the OnRequest method in Application.cfc.  That method allows you to filter requests and give them special processing.

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/805-ColdFusion-Application-cfc-OnRequest-Creates-A-Component-Mixin.htm

In your example, you could take "John", or any string, if it exists at the root, and

```
<cfinclude template="#application.baseHREF#/users.cfm?userid=#userID#" />
```

If you define baseHREF in OnApplicationStart.

Comment: To work with non .cfm extensions you need to configure the web server to tell CF to process those (e.g. .html) and I don't be believe this handles folder-like requests (i.e. `/folder`).

Comment: Good point.  I didn't realize that ColdFusion was limited in this way... bummer.

Answer (score 1):

If you decide to use a tool like ISAPI Rewrite (not free) which allows you to write Rewrite rules similar to those used in Apache, you'd add:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /users.cfm?userid=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

You can also add folders or other URLs to **exclude** from this rule with something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(assets|images|xml|tasks) [NC]
RewriteRule ^_admin/(.*)$ /_admin/index.cfm/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

I would recommend using a rewrite rule over handling it in CFML to reduce the processing handled by the CF server.